# iphone keyboard unicode mapping

Tags: ios, iphone, unicode, keyboard

I'm working on some internationalization of an iphone app, and I'd like to know the possible input code-points from the iphone build-in keyboard directly, which is supposed to be a smaller sub-set of the whole unicode planes.

Those keyboards are listed in Settings-> International->Keyboards. There are about 70 different keyboards. Is there some official documents from Apple? I googled around but didn't find much useful.

Comment: [try this][1] this link solve my issue ..............,,,,,,,,,


  [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/how-can-i-type-or-input-unicode-characters-using-a-code-point-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 5):

There is an apple document as well as tutorial available to Internationalize Your App you can find this document here --> [**InternationalizeYourApp**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html)

If you want to get the list of Keyboard Input Type you can find it here --> [**UIKeyboardType**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType)

hope this helps you.